# Organically curved wireframe

Tags: modifiers, sculpting, wireframe

I'm looking to create a wireframe of this object to be 3D printed. I been playing around with the wireframe modifiers and attempted to curve the lines more by enhancing the creases/ applying skin modifiers/ and subdividing it. But it still isn't the exact look I want. The best I can explain this is that I would like the wireframe to not be little squares, and instead a more curved organic look - like an organic looking tessellation but made up of less lines as well. I could sculpt it from scratch but I'm also looking to create a few variations and hoping there is some way that is simpler that I'm missing. [image] :quick sketch I did, I just want the wireframe to be less lines and smoother lines (less of a grid look

Here is the wireframe I have now:

[image]

I'm not too picky about the outcome, just want to see the possibility of curving the lines more. It can even be the curving of the actual object - just wondering if this should be sculpted or if there is a simpler way I'm missing. Thank you in advance and hoping this all makes sense!

[image]

Comment: have you tried a voronoi mesh? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/217518/how-can-i-improve-the-quality-of-a-voronoi-style-mesh?rq=1

Comment: you could also try this approach https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145697/find-a-way-to-voronoi-structure

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet is with the built-in Tissue add-on, that thing is a beast. Check a couple of tutorials by the creator, Alessandro Zomparelli. For example, on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9RDIQvBB8XQ) you'll see pretty much the same I will show you, and much more.

## Install the Tissue add-on

[image: screen capture showing the Tissue add-on enabled on the Add-ons manager]

1. Go to *Edit > Preferences*
2. Go to *Add-ons* tab on the left.
3. Search for tissue and enable the check at the left of the result called "Mesh: Tissue".
4. The add-on will add a new tab called "Tissue" on the <kbd>N</kbd> side panel in the 3D viewport.

[image: blender screen capture showing the location of the Tissue add-on controls]

## How to use

You'll need two objects and the add-on will create a third one as the result of the operation :

[image: the three objects, ordered from left to right]

1. First, the **base object** that you want to tessellate/convert to wireframe. Each face of this object will become one "cell" on the mesh. For this to work nicely, you´ll have to follow a quad modelling technique (that is, your mesh has to be constructed from loops of squares as much as possible). You can then add a Subdivision Surface modifier to this base object (but **do not apply it**) to round it off. If this is not enough roundness for you, you can use a Multiresolution modifier instead, and sculpt as much detail as you want on increasing subdivision levels. On the image, this base object is represented by the rounded square marked as 1 (it's just the default cube with a subdivision surface modifier at level 4).
2. A **frame object**, a reference to the shape you want to give to each cell of your wireframe. On the picture, it's the one marked as 2. Remember that the add-on pretty much replaces each face of your base object with this frame object, so in general you´ll have to watch out for internal faces. In my example, I deleted all the faces around the edge of the frame.
3. Once you have these two objects, select the frame first and the base last, then go to the Tissue panel and press "Tessellate" at the top. An operator panel will appear :

[image: Tissue Tessellate operator panel]

4. The add-on is non-destructive, so don´t worry too much about getting it right and experiment. For starters, uncheck the "Use Modifiers" setting for the Base object, and choose "Patch" as the Fill Mode, then press OK at the bottom of the operator panel. In my example, I get the object marked as 3 on the picture above.
5. After that, you can edit both the base and the frame, then go back to the resulting object, go to its Data properties (in the *Properties* panel). There you´ll find a section created by the Tissue add-on, allowing you to update the mesh and touch all the parameters found on the initial operator panel.